# Get the current location on android into the maps app via an html link

Tags: android, html, google-maps, geolocation, gps

On an iphone you can put "Current Location" into the start field of the google maps app to start directions from your current location. Is there something similar on android?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the coordinates with you already(by querying the gsp) you can do a MapController.animateTo(GeoPoint) to center your app to your current location. Was that your question or you wanted to know how to get the coordinates from gps?

Comment: i mean with a link on a webpage

Comment: what he means is that on iphone you can just use http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current Location&daddr=3333 Some Address 33331.  This does not work on Android for Current Location.  Is there something similar?

Comment: maps.google.com/maps?q=33.33,-111.11 - get the coordinates using javascript on the navigator object.